# Integrate mat-table with observable and HTTP request

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

Hi I just want display in mat-table result of HTTP REQUEST.

I don't want why I can't display.

My component :

```
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['id'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();

constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
  this.httpService.accounts.subscribe(users => { this.dataSource.data = users; });
}

ngOnInit() {
}
```

My html :

```
<mat-table>
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>id</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.id}}</mat-cell>>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

When I `console.log` I have all user with property id.

Comment: You need to bind mat-table dataSource with the dataSource in your code: `<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">`

Comment: Thank I'm bad sorry

Comment: Did @GCSDC's suggestion solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call _updateChangeSubscription() to update the view whenever datasource changes. MatTable does not honor changes implicitly.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();

constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
  this.httpService.accounts.subscribe(users => {
    this.dataSource.data = users;
    this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
  });
}
```

Comment: @Mattis.h, have you tried the solution? or solved the problem?